# Find the inverse of $(\cos t,\sin t,t)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, inverse

Let $c:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with:

$$ c(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,t) $$

Check if $c:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow c(\mathbb{R})$ is invertible and if so, is the inverse continuous?

**My attempt:**
Obviously the fuction is a bijection, so let's find the inverse. So to find $c^{-1}(x,y,z)=t$,  comes down to solving the system:$$ \begin{cases} \cos t=x \\ \sin t=y \\ z=t  \end{cases}$$

So,
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1+t^2 \Rightarrow t= \pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2-1}.$$
I think this is not right, Any ideas?

Comment: You should avoid words like "it's obvious" even though it is. Can you show why it is bijective?

Comment: $c$ is not a bijection because it is not surjective. For example, there's no real $t$ where $c(t)=(0,0,0)$.

Comment: It is surjective to its image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find a function in the $x,y,z$ coordinates that gives gives back $t$. So look at $z=t$. That is, take the projection to the $z$-axis.

Comment: So the inverse is $c^{-1}(x,y,z)=z$?

Comment: @lebong66 yes. More generally there is always a bijection between the domain of a function, and the graph of the function (pretty much by definition of a function).

Answer (score 0):

There's a more direct approach. Suppose that $f(t) = (a, b, c)$, so $\cos t = a$, $\sin t = b$ and $t = c$. Can't you immediately deduce what the value of $t$ is?

You should also really prove that $f$ is a bijection instead of saying it is "obvious".